# Auto populate list answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

I have a list that is quite long as to what can go in cell B6. Is there a way that when you type the first 3 letters, a word from the list will auto-populate?

Comment: try data validation (should be in the data tab -> Data tools section).

Comment: One is `Flash Fill` in Data TAB,,, another is File, Advance then check **Enable Auto Complete For Cell Value** and below is **Flash Fill** or if U are fix with first 3 characters then fill so u may use VBA macro.

Comment: Hi @Nora,, another is, hit `DEVELOPER TAB`,, then `Design` and `Insert` then find `ActiveX Control Combobox` and draw on Sheet. Right click it then get `Properties`, find `Match Entry` and select 1st option `Match Entry First Letter`.